# How to use the GPU with Tensorflow 2.11?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

According to this link: //pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/ , the "tensorflow-gpu" package is no longer supported and users should instead use the "tensorflow" package, which supposedly supports the GPU.

However after, installing the tensorflow 2.11 package, it will not even detect my GPU device. It only runs on the CPU. How does one use the GPU with Tensorflow 2.11?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Tensorflow 2.10 is the last version to support the GPU on windows: https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/2-10-last-version-to-support-native-windows-gpu/12404